# Pandas goupby and percentage on same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I just started learning pandas and numpy recently and a use case where I need to groupby data
on the basis of date and calculate the percentage of time the status was up (i.e. count(up)/total_count()) per month.

```
    date                                             status
   2017-08                                            up
   2017-08                                            down
   2017-08                                             up
   2017-08                                             up   
   2017-09                                             down
   2017-09                                             up   
   2017-09                                             down
   2017-09                                             up

date.      percentage
2017-08     75
2017-09     50
```

As I am from software engineering background and I am taking step by step approach of getting the count first and then divide to get the final output. However when I try to print count df I see the count column doesn't have any column header. How can I get header for it? and is there a way I can do it in one command?

```
df_up = df[df['status'] == "up"]
count_up = df_up.groupby(['date']).date.count()
total_count = df.groupby(['date']).date.count() 
print (count_up)

date
2017-08     705
2017-09    5598
2017-10    3419
2017-11    1476
2017-12     758
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have `pd.crosstab`

```
P_df=pd.crosstab(df.date,df.status,normalize='index')*100
status   down    up
date               
2017-08  25.0  75.0
2017-09  50.0  50.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 res=(df.groupby('date')['status'].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack('status')*100).astype(int).reset_index()

status     date  down  up
0       2017-08    25  75
1       2017-09    50  50
```